# How to deleteMany in MongoDB with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wan't to create a script which is going to delete all documents inside a specific collection in MongoDB.

**Full Code:**

```
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Sorry unable to connect to MongoDB Error:', err);
    } else {

        let database = db.db('CryptoCurrencies');

        var collection = database.collection('ADABTC');

        collection.deleteMany({}, function(err, results) {
            console.log(results.result);
        });

        db.close();
    }
});
```

I receive this error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined`

I have a database with name - `CryptoCurrencies` and I have few collections inside it with this names `"ADABTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC"`.

Goal: Create a script which is going to delete all documents inside a different collection but don't delete collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` and `deleteMany` callbacks will only be called with and have no field `results`:

> A document containing:
> A boolean acknowledged as true if the operation ran with write concern or false if write concern was disabled
> deletedCount containing the number of deleted documents
> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#db-collection-deletemany

Answer (score -1):

Please use

```
collection.remove({})
```

The argument to `remove()` is a filter document, so passing in an empty document means remove all documents:

For more details you can read [here in doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)